# mapping a Dictionary using AutoMapper to a List and storing it's key

Tags: automapper, automapping

I have an object, let's call it `Sprite` which has a `Dictionary<string, SpriteMapImageWrapper>` called `SpriteImages`. The key is a string, which needs to be 'stored' in the mapped object. This Dictionary needs to be mapped into a flat `List<SpriteMapImageInfo>`.  All other properties are identical, yet the dictionary key needs to be mapped to `SpriteMapImageInfo.Key`.  Is this possible using AutoMapper?

```
public class SpriteMapImageWrapper
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
public class SpriteMapImageInfo
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a shot using `.Aftermap`, like in here:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Sprite, List<SpriteMapImageInfo>>()
      .AfterMap((u, t) =>
      {
          foreach(var s in u.SpriteImages)
          {
              t.Add(new SpriteMapImageInfo 
                        {
                            Key = s.Key,
                            Height = s.Value.Height, 
                            Width = s.Value.Width, 
                            X = s.Value.X, 
                            Y = s.Value.Y 
                        }
               );
           }
       }
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, using `ConstructUsing` and `AfterMap`:

```csharp
// Create an "inner" mapping
Mapper.CreateMap<SpriteMapImageWrapper, SpriteMapImageInfo>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Key, opt => opt.Ignore());

// Create an "outer" mapping that uses the "inner" mapping
Mapper.CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, SpriteMapImageWrapper>, SpriteMapImageInfo>()
    .ConstructUsing(kvp => Mapper.Map<SpriteMapImageInfo>(kvp.Value))
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Key = src.Key)
    .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
```

With the second mapping we're telling AutoMapper to construct a `SpriteMapImageInfo` from a `KeyValuePair<string, SpriteMapImageWrapper>` using the mapping definition for `SpriteImageWrapper` to `SpriteMapImageInfo`.

Next, we're using `.AfterMap` to assign the `Key` property.

Finally, we're telling AutoMapper to ignore all properties on the destination type since we've already taken care of them with `ConstructUsing`.